# Redis AOF rewrite file is as same as RDB?

Tags: redis

I find out that if no new write action was done after the AOF rewrite and RDB save. The generated AOF file is as same as RDB file. Is that correct?

And why redis choose the way that iterate the database to rewrite AOF? It means that the program should iterate the database every time start AOF rewrite. The last-time AOF-rewrite is of no help to the current AOF-rewrite. When the database is big, this rewrite may cost too much time.

In my opinion, doing real rewrite AOF file may be better. Start from the end position of last time AOF-rewrite, and rewrite the following AOF steps. I know that doing in this way may lose some performance where re-build redis database. Is there some other questions of this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find out that if no new write action was done after the AOF rewrite and RDB save. The generated AOF file is as same as RDB file. Is that correct?

YES

> Start from the end position of last time AOF-rewrite, and rewrite the following AOF steps

Say user calls 1 million `SET` commands to set 1 million keys, before the first AOF-rewrite. Then user calls 1 million `DEL` commands to delete these keys before the second AOF-rewrite. If you start from the end of last AOF-rewrite, your AOF file will contain 2 million records which are useless. Also your AOF will grown bigger and bigger until the disk is full, and reloading such a big AOF file will be very slow.